# DocuSign api - checkbox tab original vs new value for completed envelope

Tags: docusignapi

I'm using REST api for getting envelope tabs for completed envelope. Text tabs have "original value" and "value" to determine if the tab was modified. How to determine if a checkbox tab was modified by recipient? I can see the final value of the checkbox, but there is no indication that it was modified (sender can check it before sending envelope). Same for radio group tabs as well. The changes show up as highlighted in "View Data Changes" for the completed envelope. How to determine which checkbox/radiogroup tabs were updated by recipient, using REST api?

Answer (score 0):

The Rest API hasn't exposed such functionality to check who modified the Tab Value